# word for equivalence class of vectors such that v ~ av for all non-zero scalars a

Tags: linear-algebra

In English, although the words "direction" , "sense", and "orientation" are not synonymous, they all include the criteria that one condition for two vectors v and w to  have the same direction/sense/orientation is that there is a positive scalar a such that v=aw. However, in Quantum Physics, two vectors v and w are often considered equivalent if there is some non-zero scalar s such that v=sw. In French, there is the distinction between the words "le sens" and "la direction": so that, for example,  (6,8) and (3,4) have the same "sens" and "direction"(fr.) but (6,8) and (-3,-4) have the same "direction"(fr.) but not the same "sens". Since "Direction"(English) isn't the same as "la direction"(French), I do not know of a good English word to use for the meaning of "la direction" when referring to this type of equivalence. (I started to write "the sense of 'la direction'" instead of "the meaning of 'la direction'", but I don't want to explain that I don't mean 'le sens de 'la direction'" :-). ) I could write down my meaning in mathematical symbols, but I wish to explain something in quantum mechanics to a person without a good mathematical background. So, can anyone help on this terminology?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen "collinear" used for this.  Alternatively, you could say $v$ and $w$ are in the same ray.

Comment: As I understand it, collinearity is a property of a set of points, not of vectors. Also, if v = -w, in the context I am thinking of v~w but are not in the same ray, rather in opposite rays.

Comment: In quantum mechanics the scalars are complex, so this distinction does not occur.  Another alternative is to say "one-dimensional subspace".

Comment: Right,"one-dimensional subspace" solves it for the quantum mechanics case. I forgot to mention that I was using a simple case in order to explain certain concepts to a non-science person, and hence avoiding complex numbers. So, if I can repeat my question, forgetting my comments about quantum mechanics, and look at the case where you partition a vector  space over R^n into equivalence classes [w]={v|there exists a non-zero real scalar r such that v=rw}. Again, to put this in ordinary language in French, "direction"<>"sens", but in English?